# Coda-slider Debugging "no-js" tag not being removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, javascript-framework, coda-slider

Not really sure what's going on here, been staring at this for hours :/ ... basically, I'm implementing CodaSlider using the same CSS, same div id's, and same code as another project but it's not initializing the script and the "coda-slider-no-js" tag is not being removed.

The only thing that would be different would be that paths for the respective JS files (which I have checked and verified that they are in fact loading).

Any ideas for debugging (there is no coda-slider.css file because I have included the relevant styles inside my main style.css file).

Here's the page where it should be working:
http://easterndancer.com.s66112.gridserver.com/gallery/video/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a few issues (but you have just changed the source whilst I was debugging!)

- I cannot see the main_slide element that you are trying to use for the slider. When you initialise the coda slider $('#main_slide').length is zero. Are you sure this element exists in the dom?
- You are including both full and packed versions of the easing script file. (as a rule do not use packed - it can cause issues, use minified with gzip compression - notice jquery does not come with a packed option anymore)
- Also are you sure the plethora of plugins you are using are compatible with the jquery 1.4.2?
- You have duplicate id's in the dom "upcoming_events" - (always try to test your dom using the [w3c validation tool](http://validator.w3.org/)). Duplicate id's can lead to unexpected results with jQuery.
- Off Topic - Your initial page load is 1.2Mb which is very large, consider reducing the image quality/sizes

Comment: Thanks for all the pointers.  Much appreciated!  I got it working now, problem turned out to be conflict between jQuery.crossSlide and CodaSlider.  Rearranging their order solved the issue.  Will take all of the other suggestions into consideration.  Thanks so much, cheers!